# How use Class Attribute with middle table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this action method in Asp.Net Core Web Api project.

```
[HttpPut("actor/edit")]
public void EditMoviePersonAsync([FromBody] PersonMovie model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Is Not Valid");  
    }

    Console.WriteLine("After Model Checking");
 }
```

A Custom Class Attribute

```
public class PersonMovieValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object? value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");

        return true;
    }
}
```

And I have many-to-many relationship between Movie And Person (PersonMovie middle table)

```
[PersonMovieValidation]
public class PersonMovie
{
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }


    public Movie Movie { get; set; }


    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [Required]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }


    public Person Person { get; set; }


    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public bool? IsActor { get; set; } = null;


    [Column(Order = 4)]
    public bool? IsDirector { get; set; } = null;
}
```

But when I use this method (Custom Class Attribute with my models) it runs and
Console.WriteLine("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"); line works but when I use this with
PersonMovie class it doesn't run at all. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add validation to a model,you can try to use `IValidatableObject`:

```
public class PersonMovie : IValidatableObject
{
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }


    public Movie Movie { get; set; }


    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [Required]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }


    public Person Person { get; set; }


    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public bool? IsActor { get; set; } = null;


    [Column(Order = 4)]
    public bool? IsDirector { get; set; } = null;
     
     public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```